# Parsing json string representation with delimited double quote marks and booleans in python

Tags: python, json

This seems so basic that I can't believe I haven't found a simple solution. I am trying to evaluate a json string representation in python which contains backslash delimited double quote marks and boolean values.

e.g `s = "{\"data\":true}"`.

This is valid json in javascript as `JSON.parse("{\"data\":true}")` returns a valid object.

I've tried multiple methods, none of which provide the desired solution of a pythonised string representation of a json object:

Using `eval(s)` gives `NameError: name 'true' is not defined`.

Using `ast.literal_eval(s)` gives `ValueError: malformed string`.

Using `json.dumps(json.loads(s))` returns the same format of string.

The output I want is `"{'data':True}"` as my neo4j database does not recognise `\` as a delimiter for storing purposes and therefore produces an error when attempting to store the initial format. I am trying to avoid a hard replace of `\"` with `'` or `true` with `True` as there must be a better, faster and easier solution to this.

Comment: Did you not wonder what, exactly, was being passed to `json.dumps` as an argument?

Comment: Or conversely, what exactly does your database want, a string (containing some almost-but-not-quite-JSON value) or a `dict`?

Comment: Note that `s` does not contain any backslashes; those are part of the string literal syntax to allow a double quote to be included in a double-quoted literal.

Comment: @chepner I need a string representation of a valid json object, which uses single quote marks instead of backslash delimited double quote marks. Using something such as `s = "{'data': true}"` (Also valid json) works fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [json.loads](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.loads):

```
import json

result = str(json.loads("{\"data\":true}"))
print(result, type(result))
```

**Output**

```
{'data': True} <class 'str'>
```